# If $K_\epsilon=\bigcup_{z\in K}\overline{D_\epsilon (z)}$, $K_\epsilon$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be open and $K\subseteq\Omega$ be compact. If we define $K_\epsilon=\bigcup_{z\in K}\overline{D_\epsilon (z)}$ such that $K_\epsilon \subseteq \Omega$, then prove that $K_\epsilon$ is compact.

Comment: What is $D_\epsilon$ in a general topological space?

Comment: It is a disk ( or ball) centered at $z$ with radius $\epsilon$. So the whole set would be the union of the closure of those balls.

Comment: But you don't have a distance function in a general topological space.  Note that you only have the tag `general-topology`.

Comment: I guess it would be in a metric space. Is my question wrong to begin with?

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you. I made the changes to my tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, so compactness is equivalent to being closed and bounded.  In particular, $\overline{D_\varepsilon(0)}\subset\mathbb{C}$ is compact.  Now $K_\epsilon$ is the image of $K\times\overline{D_\epsilon(0)}$ under the continuous map $+\colon\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.  Clearly $K\times\overline{D_\epsilon(0)}$ is compact (being the Cartesian product of two compacts), so $K_\epsilon$, as the continuous image of a compact set, is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not wrong, it is unclear. You didn't say what is $\Omega$. The "yes" answer posted by @user10354138 is correct, assuming you meant that $\Omega$ is a subset of the complex plane (which seems a reasonable assumption, just because $\Omega$ and $z$ are likely to be used in a complex analysis text). Without this assumption, the answer need not be "yes".

Let $\mathbb Q$ denote the rational numbers with the usual metric and topology (inherited from the reals). Assuming that $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb Q$, then the answer is no, even if $K=\{q\}$ is a single point, since $\overline{D_\epsilon (q)}$ 
is never compact.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$L=\bigcup_{z\in K}\overline{D_\varepsilon}(z)$ and $\{w_n\}\subset L$. We need to show that $\{w_n\}$ possesses a convergent subsequence, with limit in $L$.

At first, there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}\subset K$, such that $w_n\in \overline{D_\varepsilon}(z_n)$, and hence
$$
w_n=z_n+\zeta_n, \quad\text{for some $|\zeta_n|\le \varepsilon$.}
$$
As $K$ is compact, $\{z_n\}$ possesses a convergent subsequence, say $\{z_{n_k}\}$, with $z_{n_k}\to z_0\in K$. Also, since $\{\zeta_{n_k}\}\subset \overline{D}_\varepsilon(0)$ 
and since $\overline{D}_\varepsilon(0)$ is also compact, then $\{\zeta_{n_k}\}$ 
also possesses a convergent subsequence, say $\{\zeta_{n_{k_j}}\}$, with $\zeta_{n_{k_j}}\to \zeta_0\in \overline{D}_\varepsilon(0)$, 
and hence $|\zeta_0|\le \varepsilon$.

Altogether
$$
w_{n_{k_j}}=z_{n_{k_j}}+\zeta_{n_{k_j}}\to z_0+\zeta_0\in \overline{D}_\varepsilon(z_0)\subset L.
$$
Indeed, every sequence in $L$ possesses a convergent subsequence, with limit in $L$.